# Angular: Why lazy-loading a decorator doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lazy-loading, decorator

[Synchronously registering a decorator](https://jsfiddle.net/4rr7azrj/4/)

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .decorator('$controller', MyDecorator);

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

[Asynchronously registering a decorator](https://jsfiddle.net/7qfcbqxd/1/)

```
$timeout(function () {
  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .register
    .decorator('$controller', MyDecorator);

  // Make sure controller is registered after decorator
  $timeout(function () {
    angular
      .module('myApp')
      .register
      .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
  }, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

Why doesn't the second example work?

Comment: What does not work? What is the error message? What does `MyDecorator` do, where is it used?

Comment: Angular does not support lazy-loaded components. You can take a look at [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad).

Comment: @Bergi There is no error, it just doesn't run

Comment: @zeroflagL I̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶k̶ ̶I̶'̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶r̶i̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶l̶i̶b̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶o̶u̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶ ̶l̶u̶c̶k̶ Confused with another one, I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, AngularJS has 2 distinct phases during bootstrap:

1. configuration phase
2. run phase

From the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

> A module is a collection of **configuration** and **run** blocks which get
>   applied to the application during the bootstrap process. In its
>   simplest form the module consists of a collection of two kinds of
>   blocks:
>
> 1. **Configuration blocks** - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. Only providers and constants
>      can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent
>      accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully
>      configured.
> 2. **Run blocks** - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application. Only instances and constants can be
>      injected into run blocks. **This is to prevent further system
>      configuration during application run time**.

In the quote above I have highlighted the sentence about **run blocks**:

> This is to prevent further system configuration during application run
>   time

Now, in the [AngularJS documentation about decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators):

> Like with `$provide.decorator`, the `module.decorator` function **runs
>   during the config phase of the app**. That means you can define a
>   module.decorator before the decorated service is defined.

So the decoration of a controller (or service or filter) is done in the **configuration phase** not in the **run phase**.

**For this reason your "asynchronously registering a decorator" example does not work**: you are trying to define and decorate the controller inside the `initCtrl` function. But the latter is called in the **run phase** and it's too late to define new decorators in this phase.

Comment: I'm using angular 1.5, however the answer seems to be valid regardless the version. Do you know how (if possible) I could achieve such an effect?